# Plotting autocorrelation as a function of time

Tags: matlab, time, statistics, series

I am using the MATLAB function `autocorr` to determine the autocorrelation of a time series shown on the left. The resulting autocorrelation plot is shown on the right.

[image]

However, I would like to have the autocorrelation plotted as a function of time instead of lags because I would like to show how autocorrelation changed over time. How can I do this in MATLAB?

Comment: Your link does not work... Why won't you upload your images directly on SO?

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately SO does not allow me to upload an image directly.

Answer (score 2):

Using;
Time = Lags / Sample_Rate

Then you could do the following;

```
[acf,lags] = autocorr(y);
figure
plot(lags/fs, acf)
```

Where y is your input signal and fs is the sample rate.